# clear interval if criteria not met

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a nut shell, I need to clear an interval for a function called `newsCheck` if the users not on the home page. Seems simple enough, i thought so too. This is causing me huge problems. I use a history api which is why the interval would not clear on page reloads and changes.

Here's what I have with the unimportant scripting left out

```
//only run if on home page
if (url == 'Home' || url == ''  || url == 'home' || url == 'home.html' || url == 'Home.html'){

    //set up interval handler for cancellation when not on home 
    var handle=self.setInterval(function(){newsCheck()},1000);

    // ...

}//close if Home clause 
else
{
    handle = self.clearInterval(handle);
}
```

Okay, `newsCheck` is a function that checks for new information from the database via ajax query (polling). This needs to be cancelled when not on home as theres no need for it.

**Extra info on history api**

I need to cancel the interval because I use a history API script to load in new pages therefore the function keeps on running even if we are not on the Home page.

To combat this I put this in the `loadContent` function of the history API.

```
$.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "AJAX/request_feed.js",
         dataType: "script"
        });
```

As you can see it runs whatever page we're on so that the `newsCheck` function can be cancelled. This is why I have the url check in the script above.

In the script with the `newsCheck` function I have put the url variable before the `(document).ready` so that the url is retrieved when the url has changed to the new url so it doesn't fetch the url of the previous page instead. Then we check for URL and run script if on `Home` and if not we clear the interval.

Comment: What kind of "huge problems?"  I'm also not sure how compatible `self` is vs. `window` (or nothing)

Comment: @gdoron sorry was in a rush. Infos all in there

Comment: Do you call that snippet on a statechange of your history api?

Comment: you could really rethink your code m8. However to clear the interval do: `self.clearInterval(handle);` instead of `handle = self.clearInterval(handle);`. And drop using `self` as reference to window object. I know it's built in javascript but not many people know about it and it's not very common behaviour to use it.

Comment: @Eru i've tried that and many other combinations of `self` `window` and without using any of them

Comment: @nbs189 so maybe your `handle` variable is in the scope of some function. I could say more if you post more code.

Comment: @nbs189 and as far as I can see, you want to use the polling function only on homepage so probably you don't event have to clear the interval, just make sure it's initialized on the homepage. The condition you used in there looks pretty bad tbh.

Comment: Can you post more of your code? Specifically, all of the context around the interval for the `newsCheck` function. I'd like to see where/what the interaction with the history api you're running into. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
//only run if on home page
if (url == 'Home' || url == ''  || url == 'home' || url == 'home.html' || url == 'Home.html'){

    //set up interval handler for cancellation when not on home 
    var handle= setInterval(function(){newsCheck()},1000);

    // ...

}
```

**Edit:** Given that you are changing code around with the HTML5 history API, what I think you need is this:

```
// Set up the handle globally, because you won't have a history event triggered right away
var handle = setInterval(function(){newsCheck()},1000);
// Cancel it right away if you're not on the home page
if (url != 'Home' && url != ''  && url != 'home' && url != 'home.html' && url != 'Home.html') {
    clearinterval(handle);
}

// Listen for history API events
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
    // Check the new url
    if (url == 'Home' || url == ''  || url == 'home' || url == 'home.html' || url == 'Home.html') {
        // On the home page now, so set up the interval
        // And we're inside an anonymous function now, so scope the handle to the window
        window.handle = setInterval(function(){newsCheck()},1000);
    } else {
        // Not on the home page now, so clear the interval
        // No guarantee that the interval exists at this point
        if(window.handle)
            clearinterval(window.handle);
    }
});
```

And I think you need to do something similar for a 'pushstate' event listener, but I'm a little fuzzy on this thing, so you'll just have to try it and see.

**Original response**

Couple of pointers.

1. `setInterval` is native code in most browser's implementations of javascript now. You don't need to scope it anywhere. See the docs and examples on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval).
2. You don't need to clear the interval on pages other than the home page. Pages other than the home page should just nave have it set.
3. Ajaxing for news once per second is pretty crazy. Once you have the code ironed out, I would strongly suggest moving to a longer interval. Your servers and your users with slow computers, high latencies, or just crappy internet service will thank you.
4. Depending on where you're getting `url` from, it might be totally bogus. Have you verified that it has the right value in it? Are you sure all the values you're comparing it to are all the possibilities?

Also, MDN has this to say about long running operations called from an interval:

> **Dangerous usage**
>
> If there is a possibility that your logic could take longer to execute than the interval time, it is recommended that you recursively call a named function using window.setTimeout. For example, if using setInterval to poll a remote server every 5 seconds, network latency, an unresponsive server, and a host of other issues could prevent the request from completing in its alloted time. As such, you may find yourself with queued up XHR requests that won't necessarily return in order.
>
> For such cases, a recursive setTimeout pattern is preferred:

```
(function loop(){
    setTimeout(function(){

       // logic here

       // recurse
       loop();

    }, 1000);
})();
```

> In the above snippet, a named function loop is declared and is immediately executed. loop is recursively called inside setTimeout after the logic has completed executing. While this pattern does not guarantee execution on a fixed interval, it does guarantee that the previous interval has completed before recursing.

I would suggest setting the timeout for the next newsCheck() call from the AJAX complete callback. That way it's still asynchronous and you have no possibility of firing off multiple requests at once.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into the setTimeout instead. I know 1 second is bogus and I only used it so that I didn't have to wait for ages for it to be in the network log. However, as I did say I do need to cancel the interval if not on Home as I have used the history API to load in new pages. Please have a look on the extra infor i've added to the question.

Comment: @nbs189 Interesting. What is the history API? Do you have a link to some docs so I can check it out?

Comment: Basically its in the new HTML5 spec and allows you to change content without initiating a full page load. A used a mix of jQuery and JavaScript to do this. I have no links on me but just run a Google search on it. I recommend the article from HTML5 rocks. Hope you find it interesting

Comment: That is really interesting... Taking a crack at some psuedo-ish code, it should be pretty close, but no guarantees ;-)

Comment: Glad you're enjoying it. It is a great feature of the new spec and you can do some really great stuff with it. Thanks very much, hopefully this will get sorted.

Comment: @nbs189 edited that puppy up, let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: I had  quick play and I can't get it to work. I had a fiddle with push state and pop state functions and an event listener seemed a good way to go I thought. However, the script with the interval function in is called in the history API script so an event listener is not the way to go. I will find a way around this and it would be nice if I could cancel the interval in the history API script but the variable for the interval is not there so I can't.